# Unity Vuforia hand/fingure recognition

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I want to make an app like this video [Hand Segmentation + Vuforia Augmented Reality](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tONbJCquGY)

The description of video tell there was two SDK could help: Hand Recognition with Intel Perceptual Computing SDK & Augmented Reality with Qualcomm Vuforia

The problem is I don't know which feature of Vuforia could support and combine with Intel Perceptual Computing SDK, is that Object Recognition and how? Any detail instruction would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this intel SDK, but I can tell you how basically this should be done. You need to have Vuforia as the 'main' app, and let them take over the camera, as done in all of their samples, and then take the image (with unity, it is shown [here](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Access-the-Camera-Image-in-Unity)) and pass it to another to another service to handle the hand detection. It has nothing to do with what feature of Vuforia you want to use.